# What plane is this instrument panel from?

Tags: aircraft-identification, cockpit

I came across this instrument panel being sold as a potential craft project. I instantly knew what I wanted to do with it. I am going to give it, filled with old pics to my father-in-law who used to be a pilot. It would, however, make for a better story if I can find out the type of aircraft this instrument panel came from. Can anyone identify it for me, please? Maybe even just a hint at where to look?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've come to the right place; if this is from a mass-produced aircraft some wise enthusiast here will probably be able to tell you. But be aware, sometimes instrument panels are just made bespoke for a specific aircraft and its almost impossible to tell which one it came from. If there are any markings and/or serial numbers on it, that might help identify it, also the dimensions may help narrow it down.

Comment: Things that stand out to me:  the "Inverter Power" and "Radio Master" labels on the right, and the various audio switches along the top being part of this main panel instead of on a subpanel.  I *think* the vertical notch right of center along the bottom is for a gear lever?  Possibly a twin, owing to all the gage holes and the doubled-up holes on the left, but it seems pretty narrow.

Comment: The existence of DME/NAV switches indicates to me this is a post-war aircraft? Can anyone confirm that is right?

Comment: The existence of DME/NAV switches indicates to me this is could be a WW II aircraft that has been updated  ;)

Comment: In what part of the world was it found? Can you provide measurements? Could even be a four engine aircraft with all those instrument holes....

Comment: Is there any part number on it?

Comment: It was in use, there are traces left from components that have been there.

Comment: Potential lead: the pointed top is typical of some DeHavilland planes. The Beaver specifically has one, but this panel doesn't seem to match that.

Comment: Try and post it here.... https://www.pprune.org/aviation-history-nostalgia/547101-what-cockpit.html

Comment: It is definitely similar in shape to the Dehavilland Dove or Heron, but there are still plenty of differences in the instrument cut-outs.

Comment: Interesting that the pilot/copilot stacks are significantly assymetric.  They must have had significantly different cross checks.

Comment: @tmptplayer or it's from a single operator aircraft. Light aircraft tend to have only one primary instrument stack, the other cutouts could be for navaids, backup engine instruments, etc. etc.

Comment: Single pilot was my thought or single placement in a helecopter.

Comment: From your second picture I can read: 
XXXX Deice Deactivated
Oxygen System Deactivated
TKS Wing Tail XXXX
     Deactivated
Fuel Transfer Deactivated
Autopilot Desctivated
Heater Inop
Although from looking at the other pictures one would think there is much more that is deactivated on this aircraft.

Comment: Makes me think it was in a bone yard. Pos mikitary?

Comment: just removed one guage and it says "Prop Ice Guard Amps". Also on the back i found to mounts that say "P/N 150 PL-12 AN800D10" but all that told me is it is a standard antivibration mount from LORD Corp

Comment: And probably the last bit of info is what appears to be an inspection stamp on a bracket on the back. see image

Comment: OK. de Havilland DHC6-100 1967 has the closest instrument panel i can find so far. it even has the strange risers on oll the screws. BUT NOT EXACT YET.

Comment: That's an incredibly neat craft idea I now want to steal.

Answer (score 5):

I was so close. I was looking at the de Havilland Otter but a mid 50s. A friend finally found it. It is a mid 70s DH-114 de Havilland Riley. Thank you verandaguy for leading to the de Havilland. That was most helpful. Now I can finish the Xmas present and be able to tell my Father-in-law the exact type of plane it came from. Cheers.

Comment: A picture of the cockpit would be really helpful.